# Regular expression in Python not working

Tags: python, json, regex, parsing

I'm working on a Python script that can download images from Flickr, among other sites. I use the Flickr API to pull the various sizes of the image I'm trying to download and identify the URL for the original size. Well, that's what I'm *trying* to do. Here's my code so far...

```
URL = {a Flickr link}

flickr = re.match(r".*flickr\.com\/photos\/([^\/]+)\/([0-9^\/]+)\/", URL)
URL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&api_key=6002c84e96ff95c1a861eafafa4284ba&photo_id=" + flickr.group(2) + "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"

request = requests.get(URL)
result = request.text

parsed = re.match(r".\"Original\".*\"source\"\: \"([^\"]+)", result)
URL = parsed.group(1)
```

Using print() statements throughout my code, I know that the first regular expression (to parse the original Flickr URL to identify the photo ID) works properly, and that the API request works properly, returning the following result (using the example URL https://www.flickr.com/photos/matbellphotography/33413612735/sizes/h/)...

```
{ "sizes": { "canblog": 0, "canprint": 0, "candownload": 1, 
"size": [
  { "label": "Square", "width": 75, "height": 75, "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_s.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/sq\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Large Square", "width": "150", "height": "150", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_q.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/q\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Thumbnail", "width": 100, "height": 67, "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_t.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/t\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Small", "width": "240", "height": "160", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_m.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/s\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Small 320", "width": "320", "height": "213", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_n.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/n\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Medium", "width": "500", "height": "333", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/m\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Medium 640", "width": "640", "height": "427", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_z.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/z\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Medium 800", "width": "800", "height": "534", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_c.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/c\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Large", "width": "1024", "height": "683", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_b.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/l\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Large 1600", "width": "1600", "height": "1067", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_4d92e2f70d_h.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/h\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Large 2048", "width": "2048", "height": "1365", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_81441ed1da_k.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/k\/", "media": "photo" },
  { "label": "Original", "width": "5760", "height": "3840", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_34cbc172c1_o.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/o\/", "media": "photo" }
] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

My code apparently breaks down after that. The second regular expression, intended to identify the download URL of the image at its original filesize, apparently doesn't find any matches. According to yet another print() statement...

```
parsed.group(1) = none
```

I setup the expression using [RegExr](http://regexr.com/), which identified exactly what I needed from the JSON result. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I suspect you'll have better luck with `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Comment: @Rawing At this point, I'll pursue almost any alternative! In this case, why would it work better?

Comment: Why don't you just use a json parser? Then you can just access the attributes that contain the data you want, and it will be automatically escaped etc... In fact you're already using the requests library. You can use `.json` instead of `.text`

Comment: Are you trying to parse a JSON repsonse using regular expressions? Sounds like you need to do `json.loads(request.content)` and go from there instead.

Comment: @jDo I'd looked into it but (I thought) I felt more comfortable with regular expressions. How would I convert the JSON result from the Flickr API into usable variables? How could I get the source URL form the original filesize?

Comment: @Andrew You would probably need to access "sizes" -> "size", pick the element in the list that has the desired width/height (if that's what you mean by "filesize") and assign its "source" to a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your `requests.Response` object has a `json` attribute that you can access directly. If not, simply `import json`, parse your `request.content` and work with the returned dictionary. Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_response = """
... { "sizes": { "canblog": 0, "canprint": 0, "candownload": 1, 
... "size": [
...   { "label": "Square", "width": 75, "height": 75, "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_s.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/sq\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Large Square", "width": "150", "height": "150", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_q.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/q\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Thumbnail", "width": 100, "height": 67, "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_t.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/t\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Small", "width": "240", "height": "160", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_m.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/s\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Small 320", "width": "320", "height": "213", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_n.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/n\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Medium", "width": "500", "height": "333", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/m\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Medium 640", "width": "640", "height": "427", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_z.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/z\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Medium 800", "width": "800", "height": "534", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_c.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/c\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Large", "width": "1024", "height": "683", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_645397d6a5_b.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/l\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Large 1600", "width": "1600", "height": "1067", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_4d92e2f70d_h.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/h\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Large 2048", "width": "2048", "height": "1365", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_81441ed1da_k.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/k\/", "media": "photo" },
...   { "label": "Original", "width": "5760", "height": "3840", "source": "https:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2855\/33413612735_34cbc172c1_o.jpg", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/matbellphotography\/33413612735\/sizes\/o\/", "media": "photo" }
... ] }, "stat": "ok" }"""
>>> 
>>> json_parsed = json.loads(json_response)
>>> for img in json_parsed["sizes"]["size"]:
...     print img.get("source")
... 
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_s.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_q.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_t.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_m.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_n.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_z.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_c.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_645397d6a5_b.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_4d92e2f70d_h.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_81441ed1da_k.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2855/33413612735_34cbc172c1_o.jpg
>>>
```

Comment: It worked! I did have to make a small change—parentheses for the print statement

Comment: Is there any way to have it identify only the URL of the entry with a label of "Original"?

Comment: @Andrew:  It's just a `list` of `dict`s.  Use the `dict` with `whatever['label'] == 'Original'`.

Comment: @Andrew You can simply add an `if` statement in the `for` loop and, as Kevin J. Chase suggests, look for list elements where "label" equals "Original"; e.g. `if img.get("label") == "Original": source_url = img.get("souce")`